# Arabic text is detached

Tags: languages, localization, fonts, tweetcaster

I have these two issues. The text is detached in tweetcaster. Along with being detached, in the browser, the reading order is wrong.

I hope upgrading the current pre installed browser or installing a separate one would solve browser trouble. But how about tweetcaster? What is the fix for that? If there is no fix except wait for upgrade, could you please suggest a Twitter client that displays Arabic text properly?

I have HTC desire running android 2.1.

Comment: I agree.. on android, it seems like there's a problem.. its not entirely with the browser but the font support of the android OS actually i think.

Comment: So would an upgrade to 2.3 help, any idea?

Comment: im not sure about upgrade to 2.3.. but Cyanogen mod (custom ROM) seems to have enhanced Right to left fonts feature.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the browsers that don't use the internal WebKit rendering engine, i.e. [Opera Mobile](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.opera.browser), [Firefox](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox), [Opera Mini](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.opera.mini.android) or [SkyFire](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.skyfire.browser). For Android 2.2 there's also [Persian Browser](https://market.android.com/details?id=bohlool.net.PersianBrowser) which uses WebKit and connects the letters after loading the page.

Comment: Okay thanks. Any solution for the Twitter client issue? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't have great Arabic support, although this has [supposedly been improved in the latest version of Android](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5597#c6798).  This is currently the [number one most-requested Android issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?sort=-stars).

An upgrade to Android 2.3 probably wouldn't make a difference, but as Power-Inside mentioned, [Cyanogenmod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/) does have improved Arabic support.

Because the support isn't built into Android, improved Arabic support must be built into the apps using libraries such as the [Better Arabic Reshaper](https://github.com/agawish/Better-Arabic-Reshaper).

[Arabic Text Reader](https://market.android.com/details?id=quindev.products.arabic) is an app that claims to support twitter in Arabic.  You could also contact the developer of tweetcaster and ask them about improving their Arabic support.

Here's an overview of Arabic support in Android by version:

[the evolution of android arabic support](http://bmaupin.wordpress.com/2012/07/19/the-evolution-of-android-arabic-support/)